# How to foreach data that not exist in another table CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to fetch data from one of the table column that in relation with another table's using `foreach` method in CI, so here's on the *left* is **crew** table and on the *right* is **contrib** table (separated with '/'):

```
+====+======+===+====+=========+
| id | name | / | id | crew_id |
+====+======+===+====+=========+
|  1 | John | / |  1 |       1 |
+----+------+---+----+---------+
|  2 | Jane | / |  2 |       1 |
+----+------+---+----+---------+
|  3 | Jody | / |  3 |       2 |
+----+------+---+----+---------+
```

On the model **taskmodel** I've tried:

```
public function list_contrib(){
    $this->db->select('contrib.*, crew.name');
    $this->db->from('contrib');
    $this->db->join('crew', 'contrib.crew_id = crew.id' 'inner);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}

public function crew_list(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('crew');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

On the controller:

```
 public function add_task(){

    $this->load->model('taskmodel');

    $data['crews']   = $this->taskmodel->crew_list();
    $data['contrib'] = $this->taskmodel->list_contrib();

    $this->load->view('add_task', $data);
}
```

On the view:

```
<?php foreach($contrib as $cont): ?>
    <select>
    <?php foreach($crews as $crew):
          if($crew->id != $cont->crew_id ) { ?>
      <option value="<?php $crew->id ?>"><?php echo $crew->name ?></option>
    <?php } endforeach; ?>
    </select>             
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

It keeps includes **Jane** in my select option. I expects only **Jody** that showed in my select option because **John**'s and **Jane**'s id are exists in contrib table. Sorry for bad english. Any ideas?

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: share your expected output

Comment: I expects only __Jody__ that showed in my select option because __John__'s and __Jane__'s id are exists in `contrib` table's `crew_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use inner join.
Try to use left or right join

```
public function list_contrib(){
    $this->db->select('contrib.*, crew.name');
    $this->db->from('contrib');
    $this->db->join('crew', 'contrib.crew_id = crew.id', 'left');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```